# I have a problem with foreach understanding laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a persistent problem with all my project and I need help understanding how to make it work.

In my view =

`URL =  mysite.com/product/40`   so here the product ID is 40

On the view I am doing a foreach loop to show all merchants that have this product. we have many merchants having many products so it is a many to many relationship.

Now on my controller

```
$product = Product::find($id);  // to find the product

$users = $product->users;  // here the user is the merchant that have the product
$store = Store::where('user_id', $user->id)->value('social');
```

Here  i get the error :

> Trying to get property of non-object

So I do want to access the store of each of the merchants in the controller how do I do this ? Because now `$user` is a collection.

Comment: you dump variable $user

Comment: $product = Product::where('id',$id)->get()

Comment: if a `product` have only 1 `user`, then change the relation so you get a user instance instead of a collection

Comment: Dumping variable $user return null ,  and even  $product->users returns null .. strange, because when i post @foreach ($package->users as $merchant) in the view, it returns me all the users

Comment: Hussein, a product has many users,   and a user can have many products

Comment: Do you have your relations set up correctly? If a product has many users it it should be `$product->users`, which you can loop through using `foreach`.

Comment: Allright i fixed my table , so now dumping $product->users  will show me a list of users.

I can loop through using foreach on view. 
But how can I , in the controller,  say = 

$time = BookingDateTime::where('user_id', $user->id)->value('availability');

If its a collection. 

because its saying = Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 2):

Please first verify if the store is giving object or not by using var_dump. After that you can have a look into https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries for more details.

Comment: Sorry this link does not help me,  $product->users  gives me a list of users,  how do i access only one of these users, one by one. 

because on my foreach loop on the view, i need them to show something on their cards

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your code to use the `whereIn()` query builder method since you have many users to a product. You will have something like:

```
$product = Product::find($id);  // to find the product

$users = $product->users->pluck('id');
$stores = Store::whereIn('user_id', $users->all())->value('social');
```

This mean your $stores variable will contain those stores owned by the users.

> PS: Be sure to check if `$users` is not empty or null so you don't encounter unexpected errors

Comment: Not working :/ its showing the same data for all the merchants

Comment: Strange though because the process as your code describes is `one product->users of the product->the stores that those users belong` The implication is that if another product has those `users` they would get the same number of stores. Is this not your intention? @AliM

Comment: So i could make another scenario for you to understand better. Lets say  I have many clinics. Now i am on page of clinic id 1 ,   So on that page i show all the staff members.  So i use a foreach ($staffs as $staff)  ...STAFF AREA ...  endforeach .

Ok now on STAFF AREA, i want to show a calendar,   if i would want to show it on mysite.com/calendar/{user_id} .  i would only have to  display {{calendar}} as variable on the page ... because it knows that i am showing the calendar of {user_id} ,,   But when i try to do this on the list of dentists, i cant because it will not find the id

Comment: i cannot just put the calendar function on the view, its a loooot of php , and there is many functions on it  and cannot redeclare them on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

1) Firstly you can use Injection to avoid this line: `$product = Product::find($id);`

```
public function your_controller_methon(Product $product) {}
```

Laravel will automatically do the trick for you and $product will already contain Product object.

2) If you have relationship, you should do something similar to this:

`$product->stores` - to retrieve all stores which contains particular product in product_id column. And you could do: `$product->stores()->pluck('social');` to retrieve list of socials from all merchants which have particular product.

About relationships you could read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2):

According to you code, Here $user is a single value, not a collection.

Change:

```
$store = Store::where('user_id', $user->id)->value('social');
```

To

```
$store = Store::where('user_id', $user);
```

It will works.

To make the $user as a collection, execute such query so that it will return array such as:

```
$product = Product::find($id); 
$user = Product::where('user', $product->user)->get();
```

This will return the collection of users of this product.

Then execute foreach loop:

```
foreach($user as $rowdata){
    $store = Store::where('user_id', $rowdata->id)->get();
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is correct? `$user = Product::where('user', $product->user)->get();` You're passing the whole collection object as second argument to `where()` function

Comment: In eloquent when you use find() then it always return a single row, not a collection.

Comment: Oh my thanks. I completely didnt notice that. But, that means it passing a full model object as the second argument then. Do you think that would work?

Comment: No, It just pass the value of user of product object.

Comment: The problem is I cant use foreach inside the controller, because its a long long function and in the function there is other functions and i get error code , cannot redeclare function name ...etc...

Comment: And also,  i made a mistake ,  its product->users,  so its many to many .

It gives me a collection of users

Comment: Please Describe your question more @AliM

Comment: @rakib So i could make another scenario for you to understand better. Lets say I have many clinics. Now i am on page of clinic id 1 , So on that page i show all the staff members. So i use a foreach ($staffs as $staff) ...STAFF AREA ... endforeach . Ok now on STAFF AREA, i want to show a calendar, if i would want to show it on mysite.com/calendar/{user_id} . i would only have to display {{calendar}} as variable on the page ... because it knows that i am showing the calendar of {user_id} ,, But when i try to do this on the list of dentists, i cant because it will not find the id

Comment: i cannot just put the calendar function on the view, its a loooot of php , and there is many functions on it and cannot redeclare them on the same page.

Comment: Actually, in laravel we can use any loop or relation. I have already done some project with this type of functionalities. But How you describe, I think it is required to review the real project. otherwise how it is possible to solve the issue I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$product = Product::find($id); 
$user = Product::where('user', $product->user)->get();

foreach($user as $rowdata){
    $store = Store::where('user_id', $rowdata->id)->get();
}
```